# Jupyter notebook not showing title or heading

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I add a title or header it is giving error in jupyter notebook. I am trying to replicate this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVLzL5E-YBM

[image]

this is my error
[image]

Comment: You need to switch the cell from Code to Markup cell. https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the cell to markdown and then add the ##text [image]